# Динамическая хеш-таблица

Tags: хеширование

Целые числа последовательно добавляются в таблицу и заранее не известно сколько их будет - может 20, а может 1000. Следовательно необходимо каждый раз, когда все ячейки заполняются, увеличивать размер таблицы. Хеш функция будет самой простой:

```
return number%hashSize;
```

где hashSize - размер таблицы в текущий момент, number - текущее число, которое нужно добавить.

Пусть изначально размер таблицы 10. Добавляем число 15. Оно пойдёт в 5ую ячейку (15%10=5). Затем, через какое-то время, когда размер таблицы станет другим, например 20, добавим ещё раз число 15. И уже оно пойдёт в другую ячейку, в 15ую (15%20=15). Хотя для корректной работы должна была пойти в 5ую.

Как поступают в таких случаях?

Comment: Может быть, хэш-функция, опирающаяся на текущий размер - не лучший выбор?

Comment: Нужно перераспределить существующие записи между ячейками.

Answer (score 3):

В создании хэша для объекта стоит придерживаться одного очень важного правила - **хэш нужно вычислять основываясь только на свойствах самого объекта**. В твоём случае это правило не соблюдается, т.к. хэш твоего объекта (числа) вычисляется основываясь на внешних факторах (размере хэш-таблицы).

В большинстве языков программирование хэш для целого числа размером в 4 байта и есть это число. А вот твоя операция

```
return number%hashSize;
```

должна быть не вычислениям хэша, а операцией поиска порядкового номера списка (в Java это называется **бакет** и представляет собой связанный список, у тебя это называется **ячейка**), в который пойдёт новый элемент.

Что касается увеличения размера хэш-таблицы, то тут никуда не деться от перераспределения элементов между ячейками внутри хэш-таблицы, пока идёт это увеличение.

Comment: "В большинстве языков программирование хэш для целого числа размером в 4 байта и есть это число." Так а если число больше размера массива? Я же вылезу за границы

Comment: Если под понятие `размера массива` подразумевается количество ячеек в хэш таблице, то не вылезешь. Иными словами **процесс добавления элемента в хэш-таблицу состоит из двух этапов**: вычисления хэша элемента и вычисления порядкового номера ячейки, в которую попадёт элемент. Вторая операция есть остаток деления хеша на размер хэш-таблицы (аля `number%hashSize`). А **остаток от деления никогда не может быть больше делителя**